# Checking for 2D Array Rotations + Reflections

Tags: c++

I have created a code that will classify a 2D array rotation / reflection into one of these categories ->

#1: The arrangement is rotated 90 degrees clockwise.

#2: The arrangement is rotated 180 degrees clockwise.

#3: The arrangement is rotated 270 degrees clockwise.

#4: The arrangement is reflected horizontally (see the sample input).

#5: The arrangement is reflected horizontally and then one of actions #1 to #3 is performed.

#6: No change.

#7: None of the above.

Unfortunately, some of the test cases I have inputted are giving me the wrong answers. Will anyone please help me understand what I did wrong in my code?

The first line of any input contains a single integer 'N'.
The next N lines contain a string of N characters that represent the original arrangement of the array.
The final N lines each contain a string of N characters that represent the rearrangement of the array.

For example, the input below is supposed to give me '5' ->

```
5
-@@@-
-@@--
-@---
-----
-----
-----
----@
---@@
--@@@
-----
```

but my current code is giving me '3'.

The input below is supposed to give me '1' ->

```
6
-@-@-@
@-@-@-
-@-@-@
@-@-@-
-@-@-@
@-@-@-
@-@-@-
-@-@-@
@-@-@-
-@-@-@
@-@-@-
-@-@-@
```

but my code is currently giving me 5.

Here is my full code, annotated with some of the comments I have made ->

```
# include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Strategy -> 
// 1. Go over all the possible solutions IN ORDER + stop at the one that corresponds to the current input 
// 2. Print out the number of the solution 

int main() {
    char a[10][10]; 
    char b[10][10];

    char input; 
    int N, output = 7; 
    cin >> N; 

    // Take in the inputs for the original grid 
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i ++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j ++) {
            cin >> input; 
            a[i][j] = input; 
        }
    }

    // Take in the inputs for the changed grid 
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i ++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j ++) {
            cin >> input; 
            b[i][j] = input; 
        }
    }

    // The output variable is originally set to "none of the above" (number 7)
    // Go through all of the "if" statements below to see if the grids match any of the other cases 

    // 1. 90 degrees clockwise 
    bool trueCase = true; 
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i ++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j ++) {
           if(b[i][j] != a[N - j - 1][i]) {
               trueCase = false; 
           }
        }
    }

    if(trueCase) {
        output = 1; 
    }

    // 2. 180 degrees clockwise 
    trueCase = true; 
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i ++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j ++) {
            if(b[i][j] != a[N - 1 - i][N - 1 - j]) {
                trueCase = false; 
            }
        }
    }

    if(trueCase) {
        output = 2; 
    }

    // 3. 270 degrees clockwise
    trueCase = true; 
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i ++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j ++) {
            if(b[i][j] != a[N - j - 1][N - i - 1]) {
                trueCase = false; 
            }
        }
    }

    if(trueCase) {
        output = 3; 
    } 

    // 4. Reflected horizontally
    trueCase = true; 
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i ++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j ++) {
            if(b[i][j] != a[i][N - j - 1]) {
                trueCase = false; 
            }
        }
    }

    // If there is horizontal reflection + one of the actions #1 to #3 is performed, set "output" to 5 
    // If there is just a horizontal reflection and nothing more, set "output" to 4 

    if(trueCase && (output == 1 || output == 2 || output == 3)) {
        output = 5; 
    } else if (trueCase) {
        output = 4; 
    }

    // 6. No change
    trueCase = true; 
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i ++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j ++) {
            if(b[i][j] != a[i][j]) {
                trueCase = false; 
            }
        }
    }

    if(trueCase) {
        output = 6; 
    }

    cout << output << endl; 

    return 0; 
}
```